# Set Excel's ruler to Pixels (2016)

Tags: microsoft-excel, layout, measurement

[image]

Excel doesn't give you an option to measure things in pixels.  Is there any way to set this or add these units to the list?

I'm tired of having to click-and-drag while resizing to get the pixel units to show up.  I'm working with a lot of images, so pixels are basically the only way to do anything accurately.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that it makes sense to use pixels, you can use the formatting dialog box and specify dimensions in pixels rather than the default inches (or cm, depending on whether you live someplace sensible or in the US).

In the size box, type e.g. 192px.
In most cases, as soon as you click or tab out of the box, it'll convert that to the default measurement system (probably 2" for US systems).

I say probably because it depends on the Windows display setup, usually but not always 96 dpi.

I don't think that you can specify pixels for the ruler though.

Comment: Not a perfect fix, but it works! Thanks!